action-value function in terms of state value function
I am reading Sutton&Barto's book. I stucked at exercise 3.13. The question is write qπ in terms of vπ and p(s′,r∣s,a). I traced these steps:
$q_\pi(s,a) = \sum_g g \text{ Pr}\{G_t=g|S_t=s, A_t=a\}$
$= \sum_g g \sum_{s'} \text{ Pr}\{G_t=g, S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\}$
$= \sum_g g \sum_{s'} \text{ Pr}\{G_t=g|S_{t+1}=s', S_t=s, A_t=a\} \text{ Pr}\{S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\}$
$= \sum_{s'} \text{ Pr}\{S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\} \sum_g g \text{ Pr}\{G_t=g|S_{t+1}=s', S_t=s, A_t=a\}$
How can I continue from there or my logic is true ?

To start correctly you need the recursive property of the return $G_t=R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}$, then following your nonstandard notation with the four-argument transition probability as required in this exercise you arrive at:
\begin{align*}
q_\pi(s,a) &= \mathbb{E}_\pi[G_t | S_t =s, A_t = a] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_\pi[R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1} | S_t =s, A_t = a] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_\pi[R_{t+1} | S_t =s, A_t = a] +\gamma \mathbb{E}_\pi[G_{t+1} | S_t =s, A_t = a] \\
&= \sum_{s', r} \text{Pr}\{R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\}r \\
&+ \gamma \sum_{s', r} \text{Pr}\{R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\}\mathbb{E}_\pi[G_{t+1} | S_{t+1}=s'] \\
&= \sum_{s', r} \text{Pr}\{R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s'|S_t=s, A_t=a\}[r + \gamma v_{\pi}(s')]
\end{align*}
The last step is from the definition of $v_{\pi}$ per (3.12).
